# Another "reloadData calls numberOfRows, but not cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I know this question has been asked again and again. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305024/reloaddata-calls-numberofsections-numberofrows-not-cellforrowatindexpath?rq=1) summarized some common causes, but none applies to me:

> Every answer I've seen when searching has been a variation of: 1) The tableView is nil 2) numberOfRowsInSection is 0 3) tableView's delegate/data source not set 4) calling reloadTable on the wrong uiTableView.

The answer to that post was the tableView was not displayed before another call to reloadData, which is not my case either. My actual code is a bit lengthy, so I would just paste the parts that I think is related. Feel free to ask me to paste more. Note that `competitorsTable` has been added to the view in the story board.

```
@interface CartItemViewController : TrackedUIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
//...
@end

@interface CartItemViewController ()
//...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *competitorsTable;
@end

@implementation CartItemViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ...
    NSAssert(self.competitorsTable, @"Competitor table should not be nil");
    self.competitorsTable.dataSource = self;
    self.competitorsTable.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateCompetitors];
}

- (void)updateCompetitors
{
    MBProgressHUD *indicator = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.hostView animated:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        while (![self.product isLoaded]) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }
        [self.product loadCompetitorsPriceForConditionValue:self.conditionValue];
        NSDictionary *competitors = self.product.competitors[@(self.conditionValue)];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (competitors) {
                if (competitors.count > 1) {
                    self.hostView.hidden = NO;
                    self.hostView.hostedGraph = [[CompetitorGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds Competitors:competitors];
                    NSAssert(!self.competitorsTable.hidden, @"Competitor table should not be hidden");
                    [self.competitorsTable reloadData];
                } else {
                    self.hostView.hidden = YES;
                }
            } else {
                self.hostView.hostedGraph = nil;
            }
            [indicator hide:YES];
        });

    });
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSDictionary *competitors = self.product.competitors[@(self.conditionValue)];
    if (competitors.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: %s returning 0", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d", competitors.count);
    }
    return [self.product.competitors[@(self.conditionValue)] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Sort names according to its price
    NSDictionary *competitors = self.product.competitors[@(self.conditionValue)];
    NSArray *names = [competitors.allKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id name1, id name2) {
        if ([competitors[name1] floatValue] > [competitors[name2] floatValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if ([competitors[name1] floatValue] < [competitors[name2] floatValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }
    }];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"vendor"];
    NSString *vendorName = names[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = vendorName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = competitors[vendorName];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Competitors' Offer";
}
@end
```

When the view is opened, there are two calls to numberOfRowsInSection, one returns 0, which is normal because the competitors information hasn't been loaded, the other returns a number greater than 0. But cellForRowAtIndexPath is called in none of the cases.

Comment: This may be a silly comment, but in your code does `competitors.count` (which you log) somehow return a different result than `[self.product.competitors[@(self.conditionValue)] count];` (which you return?

Comment: Just tried returning `competitors.count`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called when the count is 5. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

After hours of debugging, I finally found the problem: I didn't set the struts and springs right, making the table be squeezed to 0 height. Because it is not shown, cellForRowAtIndexPath was not called